# Didn't get warning for empty citation

Tags: bibtex, citing, warnings, latex-base

My document has an empty citation `\cite{}`. I'd expected to get some warning about it.

Is it a bug? (if not - why?)
Is it possible to enable checking for such cases?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

    \cite{Goodfellow2014a}
    \cite{}

    \bibliography{main}
    \bibliographystyle{plain}

\end{document}
```

and main.bib:

```
@misc{Goodfellow2014a,
    author = {Goodfellow, I J and Shlens, J and Szegedy, C},
    title = {{Explaining and harnessing adversarial examples}},
    year = {2014}
}
```

I'm using pdflatex and bibtex.

Comment: I'm almost tempted to say it is a bug: if you go `\cite{Goodfellow2014a,somethingelse,}` then you do get a warning about the empty entry from the trailing , but a completely empty list is silently accepted

Comment: I think it classifies as a bug and should be fixed because people may rely on fixing cites later and being warned that something is not resolved. Can you please open an issue at https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues ?

Comment: @FrankMittelbach I opened an issue - https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/790

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can't change `\@for` but given that it looks like wrong behavior perhaps we can fix it by checking for an empty argument before calling `\@citex` (we can't do in that macro because too many styles redefine that).

E.g., something like

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\cite{%
  \@ifnextchar [{\@tempswatrue\@citexfix}{\@tempswafalse\@citexfix[]}}
\def\@citexfix[#1]#2{%
   \IfBlankTF {#2}%
     {\@citex[#1]{\space}}%
     {\@citex[#1]{#2}}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \IfBlankTF \tl_if_blank:nTF
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \cite{Goodfellow2014a}
    \cite{}
    \cite{ }
    \cite{  }      %tab

    \bibliography{main}
    \bibliographystyle{plain}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

Hmmm `\cite` takes a comma separated list of cite keys, if you use `\cite{aaa,bbb,}` then you get a warning about an empty entry from the trailing comma, but if the list is completely empty then the whole thing is skipped.

This is actually a feature of LaTeX's `\@for` loop macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}



\@for \tmp:=aa,bb,\do{\typeout{1 [\tmp]}}

\@for \tmp:=\do{\typeout{2 [\tmp]}}

\end{document}
```

produces terminal and log output

```
1 [aa]
1 [bb]
1 []
```

where the first loop includes an iteration with an empty value but the second loop has no iterations at all.

This might be a bit unexpected but `\@for` has been that way since the earliest latex releases, so almost 40 years now and it is used in multiple places in the latex format and in packages.

`\@for` is documented as accepting (and by implication skipping) lists of length 0

```
% \@for NAME := LIST \do {BODY} : Assumes that LIST expands to A1,A2,
%      ... ,An .
%      Executes  BODY  n  times, with  NAME = Ai  on the i-th iteration.
%      Optimized for the normal case of n = 1.  Works for n=0.
```

so arguably the unexpected behaviour is that the trailing comma isn't ignored.